# XDEBUG won't step in to functions on different files in PhpStorm and Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I have the following configuration.

[image]

The debugger will **only** stop at break points in `public/index.php`
If I put in other files like controller it wont stop.

This is the error I get when trying to step in a function in a **different file**

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
here is the mapping

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your directories mapping?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak added, thanks

Comment: You have to specify mapping not only for index.php but also for whole project, and also for vendor dir. You should have same directory structure on local machine and on remote.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot? I don't understand. thanks

Comment: [Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/1JbEtfC1) you can find example for mapping root directory.

Comment: 1) *"I have the following configuration."* And this is **JavaScript** debug -- has nothing to do with xdebug or PHP debug 2) Please read some manuals: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm **P.S.** Based on your latest screenshots -- just provide mapping for the whole project (project root)

Comment: @LazyOne ok, thanks, if you wanna get credit, post an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for remote debugging? If so, you should edit php.ini first:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
zend_extension=path/to/your/php_xdebug.dll"
```

Next step, you must add "XDebug extension" for you browser, For example, for Firefox you can install **theeasiestxdebug**

Next step: restart server to apply XDebug settings, enable plugin in browser, add breakpoint where you need it and enable debug listener in PHPStorm: [image: debug listener]

and refresh page in browser.